# VeeValidate and YUP async lazy email validation sending requests for every input in form on background

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, yup, vee-validate

I'm trying to add lazy e-mail unique validator to my registration form. It works but when i type something in other fields (including e-mail field also) unique validator keeps running and sending request to server repeatedly. I think form level validation causes it but i couldn't find a way to turn off it. How to prevent validating `email` field in form level for annoying validation requests?

Here is the script setup:

```
<script setup lang='ts'>
// E-mail unique validator (adding method to YUP's string)
addMethod(string, 'unique', function unique(message: string) {
  return this.test('unique', message, function (value: string) {
    const { path, createError } = this;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      EventService.checkEmailUniqueness(value).then(() => {
        resolve(true)
      }).catch(() => {
        reject(createError({ path, message }))
      })
    });
  })
})

// YUP validation schema
const userLoginSchema = object({
  firstname: string().required(t('fieldRequired')),
  lastname: string().required(t('fieldRequired')),
  email: string().email(t('emailRequired')).unique(t('emailInUse')).required(t('fieldRequired')),
  password: string().required(t('fieldRequired')).min(8, t('minPasswordLength', {min: 8})),
  password2:
      string().required(t('fieldRequired')).min(8, t('minPasswordLength', {min: 8})).oneOf([refy('password')],
      t('passwordNotMatch')),
})

// Form and fields
const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema: userLoginSchema,
  validateOnMount: false,
});

const { value: firstname } = useField('firstname')
const { value: lastname } = useField('lastname')
const { value: email, handleChange } = useField('email')
const { value: password } = useField('password')
const { value: password2 } = useField('password2')
</script>
```

Form template (built using vuetify):

```
<template lang='pug'>
    v-card(width='300').mx-auto
      v-card-text
        v-form(@submit.prevent='register')
          v-text-field(v-model='firstname' :label='$t("firstname")'
            :error-messages='errors.firstname' required)
          v-text-field(v-model='lastname' :label='$t("lastname")'
            :error-messages='errors.lastname' required)
          v-text-field(:model-value='email' :label='$t("email")'
            type='email' :error-messages='errors.email' @change='handleChange' required)
          v-text-field(v-model='password' :label='$t("password")'
            :append-inner-icon='showPassword ? "mdi-eye": "mdi-eye-off"'
            :type='showPassword ? "text": "password"'
            @click:append-inner='showPassword = !showPassword' :error-messages='errors.password'
            required)
          v-text-field(v-model='password2' :label='$t("repeatPassword")'
            :append-inner-icon='showPassword ? "mdi-eye": "mdi-eye-off"'
            :type='showPassword ? "text": "password"'
            @click:append-inner='showPassword = !showPassword' :error-messages='errors.password2'
            required)
          div.text-body-1.text-red {{ err }}
          v-btn(v-if='!loading' color='success' variant='contained-text'
            type='submit').mt-5 {{ $t('register') }}
          v-progress-circular(v-if='loading' color='info' indeterminate="").mt-5
    </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to disable repeated validation on email field but [the answer here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/256#issuecomment-916164944) let me chain my validations (normally validations run in parallel) and get rid of ridiculous requests.

Here is the edited version of schema above, hope it helps:

```
const sequence = <T>(
    name: string,
    ...schemas: ReadonlyArray<BaseSchema>
): TestConfig<T> => {
  return {
    name,
    test: async (value, context) => {
      try {
        for (const schema of schemas) {
          await schema.validate(value, { context })
        }
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof ValidationError) {
          return context.createError({ message: e.message })
        }
        throw e
      }
      return true
    },
  }
}

const userLoginSchema = object({
  firstname: string().required(t('fieldRequired')),
  lastname: string().required(t('fieldRequired')),
  email: string().test(
      sequence('email',
          string().required(t('fieldRequired')).email(t('emailRequired')),
          string().test( // You can also write your custom validations via addMethod like in original post
              {
                name: 'unique',
                message: t('emailInUse'),
                test: async (value: string) => {
                  EventService.checkEmailUniqueness(value).then((response) => {
                    return response.data.is_available
                  }).catch((e) => { throw e })
                }
              }
          )
      )
  ),
  password:
      string().matches(/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d).{8,}$/,
          t('passwordMatch')).required(t('fieldRequired')).min(8,
          t('minPasswordLength',
      {min: 8})),
  password2:
      string().required(t('fieldRequired')).oneOf([refy('password')], t('passwordNotMatch')),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your validation rules inside a form validation schema, pass them independently as the second parameter of each `useField` call:

```
const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  // ditch the validationSchema
  // validationSchema: userLoginSchema,
  validateOnMount: false,
});

// Declare each field and provide validators
const { value: firstname } = useField('firstname', 'required|customGlobalVal')
// ... same with your other fields
```

After this, changing a field should not trigger validations in the others, unless you manually do it.